# No overload for method 'GetData' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, datatableadapters

i am trying to link two form together, and have created a stored proc and added to the .xsd,   but im getting this error for the siaoTA.getData();

i have done this for other forms and had no issue, i cant think what im missing. does anyone know what im missing?

```
DataTableAdapters.SiaoTA siaoTA = new DataTableAdapters.SiaoTA();

private void LoadSearch()
{
    this.dgvAssets.DataSource = siaoTA.GetData();
    Utilities.setDataGridViewProperties(dgvAssets);
}
```

Comment: So what overloads the compiler say are available?  Maybe you don't have a StoredProc defined that takes 0 arguments, so none was generated?

Comment: What does Intellisense tell you?

Comment: it says (int? persondId), but the stored proc return forename and surname.